# http RewriteCond and RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite URL like *http://www.example.com/search.php?abc*
to *http://www.example.com/abc*
using the rules below, but it doesn't work, why doesn't it match?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^search.php
RewriteRule ^search.php?q=([-0-9a-zA-Z]+) $1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `%{REQUEST_URI}` always has a `/` at the start. so `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^search.php` will never match.
- [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

  > Pattern is a perl compatible regular expression. On the first RewriteRule it is applied to the (%-decoded) URL-path of the request; subsequent patterns are applied to the output of the last matched RewriteRule.
- `?` means match for one or none of previous character when not escaped. So your `^search.php?q=...` would match:

  - `search.phpq=...`
  - `search.phq=...`

from [PCRE man pages](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

> ?      extends the meaning of (
>                   also 0 or 1 quantifier
>                   also quantifier minimizer

You will have to do this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([\w]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search.php?q=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([\w\d-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

---

- Flag `NC` (nocase) : [flag_nc <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)
- Flag `L` (last)         : [flag_l <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Comment: @user121196 `http://www.xx.com/abc` will not obviously work! you will have to rewrite back! Check update.

Comment: but I'm just checking on www.xx.com/search.php?q=abc with a single rule, it didn't get rewritten to www.xx.com/abc

Comment: looks like the culprit was that you need to have two slashes to escape the "?".  RewriteRule ^search\.php\\? /xx [L]

Comment: @user121196 Nope. A single \ is sufficient. Check the answer for an update about rewriterule.

Comment: @user121196 Flag R (redirect):[flag_R Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r). `301` is for permanent redirection